# Scala Pickling: Some of the constructor parameters could not be serialized

Tags: scala, serialization, scala-pickling

When I try to json pickle an instance of this class (using this line: cls.pickleTo(....) ),
N, timeWindow and lastN parameters do not show up in the result. No problem with other parameters. Any tips for this problem?

```
class CluStream(dimC:Int, dimD:Int, NC:Int, ND:Int, N:Int, threshold:Double, timeWindow:Double, lastN:Int, uniqueLabelCount:Int=1){
    ........
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code you have inside the `class`?
For example, if you use `val` in front of your class properties, you'll have them publicly available and `pickling` will work just fine

Comment: Letting us know how you are trying to "json pickle" the class would help us help you too. Scala has many many json libraries.

Comment: thanks, val or var modifier solves the problem. I use scala pickling library and its json feature.